# Troubles with solving differental equations in Python

Tags: python, class, scipy, odeint

I am trying to complete [this](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/moler/odes.pdf#page=43), where I have to solve five ordinary
differential equations using `odeint` and reproduce figures given in that task.

Here is my code:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.interpolate as ip
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

d = 8.64
Mu1 = 4.95*10**2
Mu2 = 4.95*10**(-2)
vs = 0.12
vd = 1.23
w = 10**(-3)
k1 = 2.19*10**(-4)
k2 = 6.12*10**(-5)
k3 = 0.997148
k4 = 6.79*10**(-2)

p0 = 1.00
sigmas0 = 2.01
sigmad0 = 2.23
alphas0 = 2.20
alphad0 = 2.26

hs = (sigmas0-(sigmas0**(2)-k3*alphas0*(2*sigmas0-alphas0))**(1/2))/k3
cs = (alphas0-hs)/2
ps = k4*(hs**2)/cs

t_points = [ 1000, 1850, 1950, 1980, 2000, 2050, 2080, 2100, 2120, 2150, 2225, 2300, 2500, 5000 ]
y_points = [ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.5, 10.0, 8.0, 3.5, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]

t1 = np.array(t_points)
y1 = np.array(y_points)

new_length = 1000
new_t = np.linspace(t1.min(), t1.max(), new_length)
new_y2 = ip.pchip_interpolate(t1, y1, new_t)

pl.plot(t_points,y_points,'o', new_t,new_y2)
pl.show()

ft = sp.interpolate.interp1d(new_t, new_y2)

def equations(x, t1):

    p = x[0]
    alphad = x[1]
    alphas = x[2]
    sigmad = x[3] 
    sigmas = x[4]

    dpdt = (ps-p)/d + ft/Mu1
    dalphaddt = (1/vd)*(k2-w*(alphad-alphas))
    dalphasdt = (1/vs)*(w*(alphad-alphas)-k2)
    dsigmaddt = (1/vd)*(k1-w*(sigmad-sigmas))
    dsigmasdt = (1/vs)*(w*(sigmad-sigmas)-k1-(ps-p)/d*Mu2)

    return [dpdt, dalphaddt, dalphasdt, dsigmaddt, dsigmasdt]

solve =  sp.integrate.odeint(equations, [p0, alphad0, alphas0, sigmad0, sigmas0], t1)
```

It seems like this part:

```
dpdt = (ps-p)/d + ft/Mi1
```

is wrong and I have no idea how to solve it.

The error says:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'interp1d' and 'float'.

Any ideas and advices are much appreciated.

EDIT: When I apply changes suggested by meowgoesthedog, I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-324757833872>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('E:/Data/Project 2/project2.py', wdir='E:/Data/Project 2')

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "E:/Data/Project 2/project2.py", line 59, in <module>
    solve =  odeint(equations, [p0, alphad0, alphas0, sigmad0, sigmas0], t1)

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py", line 233, in odeint
    int(bool(tfirst)))

  File "E:/Data/Project 2/project2.py", line 51, in equations
    dpdt = (ps-p)/d + ft(t1)/Mu1

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\polyint.py", line 79, in __call__
    y = self._evaluate(x)

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 664, in _evaluate
    below_bounds, above_bounds = self._check_bounds(x_new)

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 696, in _check_bounds
    raise ValueError("A value in x_new is above the interpolation "

ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`interp1d`'s documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

> `ynew = f(xnew)   # use interpolation function returned by interp1d`

It returns a function / callable object which takes a value `x` and returns the interpolated value of `f(x)`. In your case `"x" = t`:

```
dpdt = (ps-p)/d + ft(t1)/Mu1   # pass t1 to ft to obtain interpolated value
```

---

**UPDATE**

1. This new error is due to `odeint` sampling the function `f(t)` at values of `t` **beyond** the last value of `t_points`. This is necessary for error correction and there is no option to prevent `odeint` from doing so. However, we can instead **extrapolate** `f(t)` beyond the supplied samples, using `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`:

   ```
   from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

   ...    

   ft = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(t1, y1, k=1)
   ```

   As with `interp1d`, this returns a function with the same signature. However, after applying this fix the result becomes:

   [image]

   Which is of course incorrect.
2. You have declared `hs, cs, ps` outside of the function as constants. In-fact they are **functions** of  the `alpha*` and `sigma*` variables, so have to be evaluated during each call to `equation`:

   ```
   def equations(x, t):

       p = x[0]
       alphad = x[1]
       alphas = x[2]
       sigmad = x[3]
       sigmas = x[4]

       hs = (sigmas-(sigmas**(2)-k3*alphas*(2*sigmas-alphas))**(1/2))/k3
       cs = (alphas-hs)/2
       ps = k4*(hs**2)/cs

       dpdt = (ps-p)/d + ft(t)/Mu1
       dalphaddt = (1/vd)*(k2-w*(alphad-alphas))
       dalphasdt = (1/vs)*(w*(alphad-alphas)-k2)
       dsigmaddt = (1/vd)*(k1-w*(sigmad-sigmas))
       dsigmasdt = (1/vs)*(w*(sigmad-sigmas)-k1-(ps-p)/d*Mu2)

       return [dpdt, dalphaddt, dalphasdt, dsigmaddt, dsigmasdt]
   ```

   The result now matches the graph in the exercise... almost.

   [image]
3. You passed `t1` as the horizontal axis variable to `odeint`. It only has 14 elements which is too few for a smooth output. Pass `new_t` instead:

   ```
   solve = ig.odeint(equations, [p0, alphad0, alphas0, sigmad0, sigmas0], new_t)
   ```

   The result now *exactly* matches the expected one!

   [image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a bit. But my next problem is that I get error `ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.`. Do you have any idea how can I fix it?